# style part of the text within a list object in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, listobject

I try many way to style part of the data object using computed, watch, and method property in vuejs. I still have no clue what can I do to make just the "healthy" word within the 'It is healthy!' string into different style.

```
<template>
   <div='container'>
      <div v-for="item in food">
        {{ item }}
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default{
   data(){
     return{
        food: [
           { name: 'fish', message: 'It is great!'},
           { name: 'carrot', message: 'It is healthy!'},
        ],
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example using methods to split each message and determine if it should be highlighted:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="(value, name) in food" :key="name">
      <span v-for="(word, index) in words(value)" :key="index">
        <span v-if="isHealthy(word)" class="healthy">{{ word }} </span>
        <span v-else>{{ word }} </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      food: { fish: 'It is great!', carrot: 'It is healthy!' },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    words(string) {
      return string.split(/\s+/);
    },
    isHealthy(string) {
      return /healthy/i.test(string);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.healthy {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

The above demonstrates a simple way to accomplish this - you may find corner cases where it fails. You could imagine a more complex version of `words` which extracts a list of sub-strings both with and without the word "healthy". That would produce a more shallow HTML structure.

Comment: Hey, David, I try your example, it works great. But what i mean is changing just the 'healthy' word into different style rather than the whole sentence.

Comment: Got it. I've updated the answer. Give the new version a try and let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I created CodePen example:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/budiselic/pen/RzoMPo?editors=1111)

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div v-for="(value, name) in food" v-key="name">
      {{ name }}: <span v-html="isHealthy(value)"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.healthy {
  color: green;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    food: { fish: 'It is great!', carrot: 'It is healthy!' }
  }),
  methods: {
    isHealthy(str) {
      if(str.includes("healthy")) {
        return str.replace("healthy", "<span class='healthy'>healthy</span>");
      }
      return str;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you need to add some kind of identifying class on the word "healthy".
This requires modifying the original `food` data. You can use `computed` to generate a new `highlightedFood` data, that replaces "healthy" with a `<span class="highlight">healthy</span>`. You can simply style that however you want in the style tag.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in highlightedFood" :key="index">
      <div v-html="item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      food: [
        { name: "fish", message: "It is great!" },
        { name: "carrot", message: "It is healthy!" }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    highlightedFood() {
      return this.food.map(item => {
        return {
          name: item.name,
          message: item.message.replace(
            "healthy",
            "<span class='highlight'>healthy</span>"
          )
        };
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.highlight {
  color: green;
}
</style>
```

Note, if you use scoped CSS, you'll have to use the deep combinator:

```
<style scoped>
#app >>> .highlight {
  color: green;
}
</style>
```

More info on deep selectors: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors