# How to add a html class in a Vue data string?

Tags: vue.js

I have a component in Vue and I have some hard coded data. I need to add the class `font-bold uppercase` to a word in the string.

How would I achieve this in Vue?

In the below code, inside `data > need` you will see the word `HOPE`. I need this word to have the class.

```
export default {

    data: function() {
        return {
            locations: [{
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Example',
                    need: "Lorem ipsum HOPE dolor sit amet.",
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Example 2',
                    need: "Morbi et lobortis ante, HOPE eu viverra quam.",

                },

              ]
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="(location, index) in locations">
            <p class="text-base text-navy-500 leading-tight mt-2">
            {{ location.need }}
            </p>
...
```

I tried using a method similar to this, but couldn't figure it out:
I'm assumming I need a way to search and replace the word in the string...

```
methods: {
            highlight() {
                if(!this.query) {
                    return this.content;
                }
                return this.content.replace(new RegExp(this.query, "HOPE"), match => {
                    return '<span class="highlightText">' + match + '</span>';
                });
            }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I already answered something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674732). Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @DavidWeldon thanks for the link. I haven't figured it out yet, but looks like I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option creating below highlight method

1. Created highlight method inside loop
2. Check index of word-**HOPE**
3. Use v-html to using that variable

   `methods: {
        highlight: function(val) {
          if(val.indexOf('HOPE') !== -1){
           return val.replace("HOPE", 'HOPE');

          }
          return ''+val+''`

   }
     }

**working code for reference:**

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data:  function() {
        return {
            locations: [{
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Example',
                    need: "Lorem ipsum HOPE dolor sit amet.",
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Example 2',
                    need: "Morbi et lobortis ante, HOPE eu viverra quam.",

                },

              ]
            }
    },
  methods: {
     highlight: function(val) {
       if(val.indexOf('HOPE') !== -1){
        return val.replace("HOPE", '<span class="highlightText">HOPE</span>');       
       }
       return '<span>'+val+'</span>'

  }
  }
})
```

```css
.highlightText{
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="app">
    <div v-for="(location, index) in locations">
            <p class="text-base text-navy-500 leading-tight mt-2">
           
              <div v-html="highlight(location.need)"></div>
            </p>
  </div>
<div>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WNegWXx